# PFObject does not have member name 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am new to coding with swift and was following a tutorial on you tube just to familiarize myself with it. When entering the following code:

```
var testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
   testObject["Foo"] = ["Bar"]
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(self, selector: nil)
```

I received the error PFObject does not have member name 'subscript' from Xcode. I do have all the parse frameworks added and double checked the code. I also have tried the suggestions in the other answers to the question as far as deleting 
PF_NULLABLE_S from -(PF_NULLABLE_S id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSString *)key; 
in the PFobject.h but this still does not resolve the issue.
Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using the iOS 9? if yes you need to download the new parse sdks

Comment: yes iOS9 I downloaded parse on 09/15

Comment: do you have both Xcode install, make sure you are using the new one

Comment: Running Xcode 6.4, is there any way around this?

Comment: no you have to run the Xcode beta 7

Comment: Oh I was not aware there was an Xcode beta 7, would you happen to know how could I obtain this?

Comment: A simple google search for "download Xcode 7" would have told you the answer https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

Comment: go to your apple developer account and download it straight from there

Comment: wow yup just saw it thank you going to download it now, hopefully it fixes this.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem (the same error), and the solution for was to use the `testObject.setObject(["bar"], forKey: "Foo")` (for setting), or `testObject.objectForKey("Foo") as! YourType`  (the latter is not the same as object for keyed subscript.

Comment: I did the update and the code runs successfully but for some reason Parse shows no Test data anyone know what could have occurred? I did download the SDK once again

Comment: the following libraries are no longer within Xcode:

Comment: libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib

Comment: anyone know what took their place?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug!

Download release Parse 1.8.2 (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/releases)

Parse-iOS.zip -> for IOS

Parse-OSX.zip -> for MAC OS